# Power Automate - Schedule a flow to create list item if one hasn't been created today

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to create a flow that will check @ 5PM if a record has been created today, if not it will create one. I 'm running into two issues though.

1. Whether I use "when an item is created" or use "when an item is modified" the trigger continues to run and will not stop, if I don't use a trigger it won't return dynamic content for me to use in the "Get Items" node.
2. In the "Get Items" filter query what would be the correct expression to use to filter on items created today?

Comment: are multiple records getting created daily or a single record ?

Comment: Also regarding the first point that you mentioned about the trigger actions. I don't think you should any of these triggers that you mentioned. You can create a scheduled cloud flow and schedule it to run at 5:00 PM daily. You can use filter something like "Created eq utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')".....(Note: Filter I have not tested yet as I do not have access to my system. However, it will be something similar)

Comment: Dept A, B, and C need to create 1 record each day by 5 PM, if that doesn't happen this workflow needs to create those records with predefined data. Right now I'm stuck at getting items created [Today]. I took your advice and used the filter for get items, however, I'm getting the following error: "The expression "Created eq 2022-05-16T20:27:13Z" is not valid. Creating query failed."

Comment: I've used utcNow() with a bunch of formats such as ''yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' or 'MM-dd-yyyy' and maybe a few others.